# JupyterNotebook: ModuleNotFoundError No Module named 'pyomo'

Tags: windows, error-handling, pip, jupyter-notebook, pyomo

I have opened up a Jupyter Notebook and tried to import a module from pyomo but get the following:

---

```py
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f9221793da50> in <module>
----> 1 from pyomo.environ import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo'
```

When I run this code in PyCharm however I get no problems with the module not being found. Can someone help me to understand why Jupyter is unable to find the module yet PyCharm is able to? If there is some information that I am missing that would be useful please let me know and I will update accordingly.

Comment: It's possible that PyCharm and Jupyter are linked to different Python environments which have different packages installed. You should double check which Python interpreter is being used for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install it. Put this line as the first line in jupyter notebook
[image: Install pyomo]

***!pip install pyomo***

note that any missing module is installed like this.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why it needs to be installed in Jupyter Notebook when I already have it in PyCharm?

Comment: I really do not work with pycharm, but in python, you can write a configuration such that any missing module is downloaded automatically without throwing any errors. Pycharm might do this by default. I told you Idk how pycharm work. Plus, any installed python module is installed locally, so only files in local directory can benefit from the files. Downloaded modules are not global.