# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo'

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pyomo

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook with pyomo, but get this error when trying to import from pyomo.environ.

```
!sapt-get install -y -qq coinor-cbc

from pyomo.environ import *

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In \[2\], line 2
1 get_ipython().system('apt-get install -y -qq coinor-cbc')
\----\> 2 from pyomo.environ import \*

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo'
```

I have already installed pyomo with the command `!pip install Pyomo==5.7.1`. It installs correctly -- I get the message `Successfully installed PyUtilib-6.0.0 Pyomo-5.7.1 nose-1.3.7 ply-3.11` and when I check the version with `!pyomo --version` I get `Pyomo 5.7.1 (CPython 3.8.10 on Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2)`.

Does anyone know what is wrong? I've already taken a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417971/jupyternotebook-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyomo).

Comment: You can run this jupyter as an administrator but this is a workaround and you should find another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step:  If you have recently installed or updated versions, etc., log out completely and log back in to ensure you are using current environment variables.  Then...

It is likely that your `jupyter` module is running inside a different python framework than the one you installed `pyomo` in.

Check it within the notebook.  I haven't used mine in a while so it is a good example of mismatched frameworks...

In the notebook:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

In a terminal window check the default version

```
which python3
```

These should match.  Mine currently do not, but my older version had `pyomo` as well, so it doesn't fail on the import...  but look at the version...:

[image]

Terminal.  This shows the framework that I'm currently using (and by default installing new modules into):

```
% which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
%
```

If this is the case, update your `jupyter` install with pip3 in the terminal:

```
% pip3 install --upgrade jupyter
```

Then **log out and log back in**, open a new notebook and re-check:

[image]

This should ensure that the modules you installed are in the same framework that `jupyter` is using.